# Why I get access denied while getting system processes's modules?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

My application requires to get processes's modules (.dll, etc), but I get access denied while reading lsass.exe, csrss.exe's modules. Moreover, I can get without any problems avp.exe's modules (Kaspersky Anti-Virus Service) which is too started as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. C# Code:

```
            ProcessModuleCollection pmc;
            pmc = Process.GetProcessById(id).Modules;
            foreach (ProcessModule pm in pmc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pm.FileName);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: lsass.exe? Thats ring0 stuff. It is one of the most protected processes in windows. Getting into it would subvert all windows security, hence the protection.

Comment: @bradbury9 I know, but Kaspersky has ring0 driver too ( it's process protected by obcallbacks) and I can get it's modules

Comment: @bradbury9 - *lsass.exe? Thats ring0 stuff.* - of course no

Comment: depend from windows version - *csrss.exe* can be protected process (*Light.WinTcb*) - only process with the same or higher protection level can enumerate it modules. *lsass.exe* not protected. if you have debug privilege - you in general must open it with enough access

Comment: @bradbury9, "ring 0" means kernel mode. LSA cooperates closely wth the Security Reference Monitor (SRM) in the kernel, but it's a user-mode system service. It may or may not be a protected process. By default it isn't because this can be disruptive, but there's a [registry setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/credentials-protection-and-management/configuring-additional-lsa-protection) to run lsass.exe as a protected process.

Comment: The security descriptor for the lsass.exe process has a [mandatory label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965848) at system level (i.e. S-1-16-16384) that denies both read-up and write-up access to subjects at a lower integrity level. Thus, even though the DACL grants the access required to read the modules to an administrator, it's denied because typically an administrator token is only at high integrity level, below system level. However, as @RbMm points out, an admin can enable SeDebugPrivilege to get access anyway. This won't provide access to a protected process, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lsass and csrss are both Protected Processes

How to find out if a process is a protected process?

In process hacker go to lsass, right click properties, view the certificate then go to details and go down to Enhanced Key Usage, if the cert provides "Protected Process Light Verification" then it can run as a Protected Process.

You cannot access Protected Processes as an administrator even with SeDebugPrivelage.

Kaspersky is running as SYSTEM but it is not a Protected Process.

You can read all about Protected Processes here:

- https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/evolution-protected-processes-part-1-pass-hash-mitigations-windows-81/
- https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/evolution-protected-processes-part-2-exploitjailbreak-mitigations-unkillable-processes-and/
- https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/protected-processes-part-3-windows-pki-internals-signing-levels-scenarios-signers-root-keys/
- https://github.com/Mattiwatti/PPLKiller
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/protecting-anti-malware-services-